# Concatenating string and char literals in C

Tags: c, gbdk

In my code I define some compiler constants such as the following:

```
#define D_CR  '\x10'    // New line
#define D_LF  '\x13'    // New paragraph
#define D_EOS '\xFF'    // End of string
```

(these could be chars, ints, whatever ... )

And I want to use them in two ways, one in a string literal, and secondly in switch statements.

```
unsigned char dialogString[] = 
    "LOREM IMSUM" D_CR
    "DOLAR SIT A MET" D_EOS;

switch (dialogString[i]) {
    case D_CR: /* ... */ break;
    case D_LF: /* ... */ break;
    case D_EOS: /* ... */ break;
    default: printf(dialogString[i]); break;
}
```

The problem that I'm getting is that I'm mixing types and I'm getting compiler warnings.

```
dialogString.c(5) parse error: token -> ''\x10'' ; column 11
```

Is there any way that I can get this to work for both scenarios?

Comment: good question, but I'm afraid the preprocessor limitations won't allow that.

Comment: no, not `'\x13'`. It's either `13` or `'\xd'` or `'\x0d'`, maybe even `'\n'` if you're worried about character encodings.

Comment: @pmg parse error: token -> ''\x0d' ; column 11

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre does this mean i should create two compile-time constants to sort this (one char and one string)?

Comment: See [code running at codepad](http://codepad.org/qLbgyhGT).

Comment: @pmg: are you able to post an answer (I don't have access at codepad from here)?

Comment: The codepad entry is just about `\x13`, not an answer to your actual question

Comment: I'm unclear how the codepad code addresses the problem. It just seems to define the original constants, then confirm that they have been defined. No string literals involved.

Comment: Not sure if a previous answer of mine to another question suits you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595544/c-macro-turn-a-number-into-a-string