# How can I put the numeric value of an enum constant into a string in C?

Tags: c, string, enums, c-preprocessor

I need a way to put the numeric value of an enum constant into a string constant as a single byte (at compile time).

```
enum
{
    SPECIAL_CHAR = 230
};

const char *str = "hello" ENUM_TO_STR_BYTE(SPECIAL_CHAR) "world";
```

I want the resulting string `str` in memory to look like this string: `"hello\xE6world"`.

How can I write the macro `ENUM_TO_STR_BYTE`?

Of course, it could be done by initializing the string with individual characters, but that is very inconvenient for longer strings

```
const char str[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', SPECIAL_CHAR, 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

Comment: `sprintf` with `%c`?

Comment: This question may be relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595544/c-macro-turn-a-number-into-a-string

Answer (score 3):

A kludge is:

```
#define MakeIt(A, B, C) ((const char *) &(struct { const char a[sizeof A - 1], b, c[sizeof C]; }){A, B, C})

const char *str = MakeIt("hello", SPECIAL_CHAR, "world");
```

Accessing the structure with `const char` conforms with the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7 since they allow accessing any object using a character type. The C standard allows implementations to insert padding after structure members but no practical C implementation inserts padding between members that are `char` or arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a limited number of special characters, you could define macros for the string equivalent of each special character and use those in the string literals or possibly use token pasting to generate the corresponding identifiers:

```
enum {
    AE_LIGATURE = 230,
    C_CEDILLA = 231,
};

#ifdef USE_ISO_8859_1
#define STR_AE_LIGATURE  "\xE6"
#define STR_C_CEDILLA    "\xE7"
#else
#define STR_AE_LIGATURE  "\xC3\xA6"
#define STR_C_CEDILLA    "\xC3\xA7"
#endif

const char *str = STR_C_CEDILLA "a ira, et c" STR_AE_LIGATURE "tera!";

#define ENUM_TO_STR(c)  STR_##c

const char *str = ENUM_TO_STR(C_CEDILLA) "a ira, et c" ENUM_TO_STR(AE_LIGATURE) "tera!";
```

Answer (score 0):

In C there's no reflection like tool or way to make this, but you can handle it somehow using the macro preprocessor.  Just define a macro and define a series of macro calls in a file, something like:

```
dumb_macro(C_CEDILLA, L'ç')
dumb_macro(A_ACUTE, L'á')
```

and include this file (let's use the name `specials.i` for the name of this file)
Later you can include this file with a macro definition that defines your enum:

```
enum specials {
#define dumb_macro(_nam, _val) _nam = _val,
#include "specials.i"
#undef dumb_macro
}; /* enum specials */
```

and later

```
char *specials_names[] = {
#define dumb_macro(_nam, _val) [_val] = #_nam,
#include "specials.i"
#undef dumb_macro
}; /* specials_names array */
```

this will result, for the data above, after preprocessing, in:

```
# 1 "specials.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 355 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "specials.c" 2
enum specials {

# 1 "./specials.i" 1
C_CEDILLA = L'ç',
A_ACUTE = L'á',
# 4 "specials.c" 2

};

char *specials_names[] = {

# 1 "./specials.i" 1
[L'ç'] = "C_CEDILLA",
[L'á'] = "A_ACUTE",
# 10 "specials.c" 2

};
```

Then, adding a new constant is easy as editing the file `specials.i` and adding a new entry with its name and its value.